# UITableView section header does not always draw

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is a problem stumping me and my team at work.

We have a header view we are using in one section that is not always drawing. It's inconsistent, though appears to be slightly more frequent on fresh installs.

I will first preempt by stating we are not registering it to the table view and thus not actually dequeueing it. I tried that but the boss says since we are never actually re-using it he is adamant against doing so. Therefore we have it like this:

```
class DashboardViewController {
...
    var trendsHeader: TrendsHeader?
...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTrendsHeader()
        ....
    }
...
    func setupTrendsHeader() {
        trendsHeader = Bundle(for: TrendsHeader.self).loadNibNamed(TrendsHeader.identifier, owner: view, options: nil)?.first as? TrendsHeader
        trendsHeader?.delegate = self
        trendsHeader?.datasource = self
        trendsHeader?.leftDropdown.selectRowWithAction(at: 0)
    }

...
    // in heightForHeaderInSection
    return TrendsHeader.cellHeight //Height is returned properly, empty space is of the right height

...
    // in viewForHeaderInSection
    return trendsHeader ?? UIView()//Should only return UIView if trendsHeader is nil
}
```

I have tried modifying viewForHeaderInSection as such:

```
//in viewForHeaderInSection
if trendsHeader == nil {
    setupTrendsHeader()//Breakpoint inserted here
}
return = trendsHeader ?? UIView()
```

And with a breakpoint in the if statement so I should know if the `trendsHeader` is nil. It doesn't hit the breakpoint but still doesn't draw that header. If I wait anywhere from 5–30 seconds the header will show up, or if I scroll down the header will show up once it redraws the section. But I need it to show up initially as well, which it still does in most runs of the app but sometimes just doesn't. Honestly the most frustrating part is the inconsistency.

Any insight as to why this is occurring and/or a resolution that doesn't involve convincing my boss to register a view for re-use that isn't going to be re-used?

Comment: "It doesn't hit the breakpoint but still doesn't draw that header"? Well if it's not hitting the breakpoint how could it…? 5–30 seconds later the header just shows up even if you're not touching the screen? Why are you setting the owner of the `TrendsHeader` to `view`? Do you really need to have the `TrendsHeader` as a stored property?

Comment: The breakpoint should only hit if the header is nil, thus it should either hit the breakpoint or draw the header. As for storing, we do need access to the selected index of a drop-down on the trends header, so we do need a reference to it. And yes, it will draw without me touching the screen. Though I am now wondering if setting the owner to self might do it instead.

Comment: Oh right, misread that bit. Did you check to see if the `return` line in `viewForHeaderInSection` is hit when you expect it to be?

Comment: It took a while to recreate, again it's annoyingly inconsistent, but the return line is hit and the value being returned is of the TrendsHeader type (as opposed to just UIView) even in cases where the header is not drawn. So it exists, at least in memory, and it should be there. The screen is just not drawing it (nor is it touchable as far as I can see).

Also, setting the owner to self (the VC) instead of the view did not solve it.

Comment: I believe the 5-30 seconds is just another process reloading the tableview or otherwise re-calling viewForHeaderInSection, as it just went a full 2 minutes without drawing it. I had to scroll.

Comment: Did you check its frame?

Comment: I just opened it up in the Debug View Hierarcy window while the header is not displayed, and it is clearly shown there as if it was drawn on the screen, in the correct spot.

Comment: Is it covered up by something? Does it contain the labels etc you are expecting? Could try giving it a distinct background color so it stands out from the background.

Comment: The background for the Tableview is already specified as grey, and the header's background is specified as white. This allows us to embed some cells within clear views to give the appearance of the cells being on top, and to easier separate sections.

To clarify with that information, I am seeing a grey space where the header should be.

Comment: What about the other questions?   By the way to your point about registering it / dequeuing… You don't register a view that you place inside a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. The section headers are still dequeued and reused. You'd have to make your own subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` if you wanted to change that (and you'd probably still need to register it).

Comment: Neither the main screen nor the Hierarchy Inspector show anything in front of it/covering the space. On the simulator/device none of the labels show up (just the gray space that should be behind it), but everything shows up perfectly in the Hierarchy Inspector. All elements exist within the header, and the header seems to exist, but the header is not visible.

Comment: I would still double check whether the frame size and origin are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Hierarcy Inspector shows the header's height and width are 375/56 respectively, which is the desired result.

Comment: I meant directly, without the inspector.

Comment: No matter where I break and/or print, the frame height returns the expected 56 so long as I'm checking anytime after heightForHeaderInSection has finished.

Comment: Does it work OK if you use just a regular text-based section header (as opposed to a custom view)? Or if you use a view that you create programmatically instead of via a nib?

Comment: Replaced the above code within viewForHeaderInSection to just display a programatically-created label. I can't recreate the bug with the label, so hopefully we've narrowed it down to an issue either in the TrendsHeader class or how our VC is handling TrendsHeader. Thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes and without showing the class / xib, probably won't get any further insight here.

Comment: I'd love to but it's work, I don't want to risk the consequences of revealing any more than this. I will pass this along to my team, thankfully today was Sprint planning so this conversation didn't eat any scheduled development time. Would you like to put this conclusion as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: Yea, I know, just saying. No, it doesn't constitute an answer. When you solve it, post the answer, or you're welcome to update it later when you have more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found it. Long story short, the section in question is tied to 2 service calls, one for each option on the header's drop down menu. Those services had delegates who reloaded the section upon the callback functions, and they were getting them in quick succession causing the glitch.

We replaced the reload section code with reload rows code instead, so the header does not get refreshed.